# Ошибка сравнивания массивов

Tags: c#, массивы, сравнение

решил написать программу, как она работает, написано в комментариях в коде.

Проблема будет описана ниже:

```
/* Программа генерирует пять случайных чисел,
* Затем вводятся пять чисел с клавиатуры.
* Далее считается количество чисел на месте и не на месте.
* Если количество чисел на месте равно пяти(сгенерированные числа равны 
введённым),
* То программа заканчивает работу
*/

namespace Console_password
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; 
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] pass = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  //тестовые значения (закомментированные строчки ниже заполняют рандомными значениями)
        //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            //vs[i] = random.Next() % 10;
        int[] input = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //пустые значения для ввода
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(">> ");
            string[] s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');                      //
            int[] a = new int[5];                                            // заполняем с консоли массив
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) input[i] = Int32.Parse(s[i]); //

            int InPlace = 0; //цифр на месте
            int OutOfPlace = 0; //цифр не на месте
            bool[] nums = { false, false, false, false, false }; // номера цифр, которые на месте
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (pass[i] == input[i]) 
                {
                    InPlace++;       //проверяем количество цифр на месте
                    nums[i] = true;    //запоминаем позиции чисел, которые на месте
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if (nums[j] == true)            //проверяем количество чисел не на месте
                        continue;                   //тут логическая ошибка
                    if (pass[i] == input[j])
                        OutOfPlace++;
                }
            if (InPlace == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Доступ разрешён!");
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Значений на месте {InPlace}, значений не на месте {OutOfPlace}.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```

А проблема в том, что если в тестовых значениях есть число 1, и в консоль ввести пять единиц, то выведет "Значений на месте 1, значений не на месте 4"
Можете скопировать код и убедиться в этом сами.
Я не понимаю как исправить эту проблему, обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Если в коде есть другие ошибки или это очень плохой код, напишите, я просто не понимаю, как надо, ведь я недавно начал программирование изучать.

Comment: У вас тестовый массив 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. С консоли вводится 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.
В результате первая единица совпадает, 4 остальных числа не совпадает, поэтому на месте 1 значение, 4 не на месте. В чем проблема то?

Comment: Я сначала лайкнул комментарий, но потом подумал: если бы там был ввод 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, то действительно было бы 4 значения не на месте. А так 0 должно быть.

Comment: @trollingchar почему 0? Эталон - `1 2 3 4 5`, консольный ввод `1 5 4 3 2`. Только 1 на месте, 4 не на месте.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Я это и написал. 0 будет при вводе всех единиц.

Comment: @trollingchar очень странная у вас программа однако. Ведь если все-таки будет введено `1 1 1 1 1`, то тогда почему остальные единицы будут на месте? ведь на втором, третьем и т.д. месте должны быть значения 2, 3 и т.д.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko разве? Моя программа в таком случае выведет 1 на месте, 0 не на месте. А не все 5 на месте. Или я где-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: @trollingchar проблема в том, что ваша задача не оговаривает, что значит "элемент не на месте". Если рассуждать логически, значение `"на месте"` - это когда 1) значение расположено по тому же индексу, что и в эталонном массиве, и 2) равно значению по этому индексу. А `"не на месте" `- это получается то, что ЛЮБОЕ ИЗ УСЛОВИЙ 1) или 2) может быть не соблюдено, поэтому для массива `1 1 1 1 1` среди вариантов вывода `1 на месте, 0 не на месте`, и `1 на месте, 4 не на месте` последний вариант мне кажется более логичным. Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил свою точку зрения

Comment: @AndreiKhotko во-первых, это не моя задача, а достаточно известная, "быки и коровы", и судя по коду, именно ее автор и пытается решить. На месте - это когда число и там и там на одном и том же месте. Не на месте - такое число есть, но не там, где оно загадано.

Comment: @trollingchar если условие действительно говорит так, как вы только что написали, то ладно, я не буду спорить. Я потом взгляну на задачу и предложу исправления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас числа в небольшом диапазоне, вы можете сделать так:

```
public static void Main (string [] args) {
    const int n = 5,
              m = 10; // от 0 до 9

    int x = 0,                 // совпавшие местами
        y = 0;                 // совпавшие но не на месте
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // загаданные числа, n штук
          b = {5, 3, 4, 2, 1}, // что игрок ввел
          aa = new int[m],     // m это верхняя граница диапазона чисел, если от 0 до 9 то там 10
          bb = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b[i]) {
            x++;
        }
        else {
            aa[a[i]]++;
            bb[b[i]]++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        y += Math.Min(aa[i], bb[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine ($"{x} на месте {y} не на месте");
}
```

Я добавил инициализацию сравниваемых массивов, чтобы доказать, что все работает. Ожидаемый вывод: `0 на месте 5 не на месте`

Идея в том, что мы считаем отдельно совпавшие числа и отдельно считаем сколько несовпавших нулей, единиц, двоек и т.д. в каждом числе. Потом берем минимум для каждого числа и считаем что столько чисел не на своем месте.

То есть например для данных `55571` в массиве будет `0,1,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0`.

Comment: Прости, зачем нужны массивы aa и bb?

Comment: В них мы храним количество не совпавших по позиции цифр. В нулевом элементе - нулей, в первом - единиц и т.д. `aa` - для того что загадано, `bb` - что игрок вводит. По аналогии с `a` и `b`.

Comment: в следующий раз, когда будешь отвечать, лучше используй говорящие имена переменных, это повысит читабельность твоего кода.

Comment: При вводе 5 3 4 2 1 пишет 0 на месте, 4 не на месте. Надо бы изменить что-то.

Comment: @КривойИИ у меня выводит 5. Может вы ставите верхнюю границу равной 5? Она должна быть ровно на 1 больше, чтобы `Random.Next(m)` потом работал корректно. Если у вас цифры от 0 до 9, ставьте 10. Я, кстати, в ответе это написал.

Comment: @КривойИИ Наверно вы во втором цикле просто написали n вместо m.